# plot Contourplot simple

Tags: plotting

```
demElev[path_, samples_] := 
 Module[{elevUrl, x, y, markers, dem}, 
  elevURL = 
   "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/elevation/json?sensor=false"; {x, 
    y} = path[[1]] - path[[2]]; 
  pnts = Table[
    path[[2]] + {i, j}, {i, 0, x, x/samples}, {j, 0, y, y/samples}]; 
  markers = 
   StringReplace[
      ToString[#], {"}, {" -> "|", "{" -> "", "}" -> "", 
       " " -> ""}] & /@ pnts; 
  dem = ToExpression@
      StringCases[Import[elevURL <> "&locations=" <> #], 
       NumberString] & /@ markers; Partition[Flatten[dem], 4]]
path = {{41.334387, 104.574955}, {51.02568, 120.563405}}
dem = demElev[path, 120]

ListContourPlot[dem[[All, {3, 2, 1}]], 
 ContourStyle -> 
  Directive[GrayLevel[0], Opacity[0.946], AbsoluteThickness[2.5`]], 
 Contours -> {688, 1101}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ContourShading -> None, ColorFunction -> "Thermometer", 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[10]}]
```

How to draw contour plot not a sharp angle this picture??  2D[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question and I suspect others will have a problem with it as well, could you try to say it in a different way?

Comment: @halirutan I was able to reproduce the image without any error message.

Comment: how about first picture change to 2nd picture?

Comment: this sample code is working ... my quistion is processing contourplot this image...

Comment: this list about 14400 units data...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you look at the data you have imported from google, you see that the lie in a structured grid. Therefore, you can transform your list of points `{{v1, y1, x1}, {v2, y2, x2}, ...}` into a matrix of values.
With this matrix of values you can work with all kinds of smoothing filters to smooth the heights. In your particular example, one row is exactly 121 values long. Therefore, we can create the matrix easily and use a `GaussianFilter` before using `ListContourPlot`

```
data = Reverse[Reverse /@ Partition[dem[[All, 1]], 121]];
ListContourPlot[GaussianFilter[data, 5], Contours -> 10, 
  ColorFunction -> "Pastel", 
  DataRange -> Transpose[dem[[{-1, 1}, {3, 2}]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compared to your original plot this gives:

[image]